# Create table from query result

Tags: sql-server

I do have a problem with creating proper SQL statement.

Scenario, i do have a table "Excel" which is populated by SQLBulkCopy few times, after that table contains duplicates which I want to sum by "Buildneed", I have figured out way to return "consolidated" result with below query :

```
SELECT GBC, Description, sum(Buildneed) as Buildneed, Replaced 
FROM Excel 
GROUP BY GBC, Description, Replaced 
ORDER BY GBC ASC
```

Now I would like to drop NewTable if exists, create NewTable again and populate this table from mentioned above result.

So I wrote this statement :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.NewTable

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewTable] 
(
    [GBC]         INT          NULL,
    [Description] VARCHAR (80) NULL,
    [Buildneed]   INT          NULL,
    [Replaced]    VARCHAR (80) NULL
);

SELECT Excel2.GBC, Excel2.Description, Excel2.Buildneed, Excel2.Replaced 
INTO NewTable 
FROM (SELECT GBC, Description, sum(Buildneed) as Buildneed, Replaced 
      FROM Excel 
      GROUP BY GBC, Description, Replaced 
      ORDER BY GBC ASC) AS Excel2
```

I'm not receiving any error information, table is not created after running above query.

Every single time new data will come to table "Excel" I want to "consolidate -> drop NewTable -> create NewTable with new data"

Sample data :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Excel] 
(
        [GBC]         INT          NULL,
        [Description] VARCHAR (80) NULL,
        [Buildneed]   INT          NULL,
        [Replaced]    VARCHAR (80) NULL
    );

INSERT INTO @Excel (GBC, [Description], Buildneed, Replaced)
SELECT 71744, 'RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C', 2000
UNION ALL
SELECT 71744, 'RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C', 1000
UNION ALL
SELECT 76527, 'CAP_CER,10nF,0402,10%,50V,X7R', 288
UNION ALL
SELECT 86911, 'CAP_CER,10nF,0603,10%,100V,X7R', 1464
```

Expected result -> New table created with name "NewTable"

```
GBC  / Description / Buildneed / Replaced
71744 / RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C / **3000** / null
76527 / CAP_CER,10nF,0402,10%,50V,X7R / 288 / null
86911 / CAP_CER,10nF,0603,10%,100V,X7R / 1463 / null
```

Comment: First of all, I suggest to create the new table with another name, drop the old table after the new table has successfully been created and then rename the new table to the desired name - so you prevent data loss in case anything doesn't work during table creation.
Furthermore the `SELECT ...  INTO` should create a new table without the need of creating it first.
Another possibility would be `INSERT INTO... SELECT...`.

Comment: See SQL Fiddle for an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d568e/5/2

Comment: @Tyron78 I've got feeling that You described exactly what i have done here, but its not working.. i tryed another ways like You wrote for example "SELECT ... INTO" without creating table, or something like "SELECT d.GBC... INTO NewTable FROM (SELECT GBC... FROM Excel) as d" also didn't worked

Comment: You had some syntax errors in your example. The inserts didn't match the table definition and you created the table before executing `SELECT ... INTO`- don't know why you didn't receive an error there. However, if you check the fiddle example, you can try for yourself. That's why I added it as answer...

Comment: @KubaDo - why drop the table? Is there some aspect of the structure that changes? Or are you simply doing it to clear out the data? If so there's better ways (TRUNCATE TABLE comes to mind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suggest to create the new table with another name, drop the old table after the new table has successfully been created and then rename the new table to the desired name - so you prevent data loss in case anything doesn't work during table creation. Furthermore the SELECT ... INTO should create a new table without the need of creating it first. Another possibility would be INSERT INTO... SELECT...

Here an example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Excel] (
        [GBC]         INT          NULL,
        [Description] VARCHAR (80) NULL,
        [Buildneed]   INT          NULL,
        [Replaced]    VARCHAR (80) NULL
    );


insert into [Excel] (GBC, [Description], Buildneed, Replaced)
select 71744, 'RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C' ,2000, NULL
union all
select 71744, 'RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C' ,1000, NULL
union all
select 76527, 'CAP_CER,10nF,0402,10%,50V,X7R' ,288, NULL
union all
select 86911, 'CAP_CER,10nF,0603,10%,100V,X7R' ,1464, NULL;

SELECT Excel2.GBC, Excel2.Description, Excel2.Buildneed, Excel2.Replaced
  INTO NewTable
  FROM (SELECT GBC, Description, sum(Buildneed) as Buildneed, Replaced FROM Excel GROUP BY GBC, Description, Replaced) as Excel2;

SELECT *
  FROM NewTable
```

See SQL Fiddle for an example: sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d568e/5/2

Comment: This is exactly what i did.... I see from SSQL Fiddle its working, but when i execute this from Visual Studio 2019 by creating newQuerry on table "Excel" its not returning  results, i should also see "NewTable" in "Tables" where i have executed querry right ?

Comment: In your example you have a `DROP TABLE` and a `CREATE TABLE` before the `SELECT INTO` . Yes, if executed sucessfully, you should find the NewTable in your DB (after refreshing in Visual Studio). Oh, and if your default schema is not dbo, you should put this in the `SELECT INTO` as well...

Comment: Ok i see the problem.. All of those statements cant be run in single querry ?

Comment: They can, but possibly you will have to add `GO` between them... In fiddle I Executed them in one single execution (except the creation of the example table).